# A copy of a NSManagedObject

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

When I send the `copy` message to a `NSManagedObject` subclass, I get this error:

*'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[JTPModel copyWithZone:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8d19a10'*

Why am I not supposed to make copies of `NSManagedObjects`?

Comment: Typically to make a copy you would create a new nsmanagedobject and copy the attributes from the original.  That way you have two objects with the same attributes, but they are two different objects.  You can check by getting their objectID, they will be different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@aleroot's link is a good one. To the basic question of why, the problem is that that there is no single answer to how copying should be performed. You must decide how your objects should be copied. This is true of all objects in all object-orient languages, not just `NSManagedObject`.

Consider the case of a parent object with two children objects and a city object that the parent lives in. If I copy the parent, should I also make copies of the children? Probably yes, since you would not want the same children to have multiple sets of parents. Should I make a copy of the city? Probably not, since each person does not get their own copy of Chicago. You should just make a new link there. You can only know this because you know what the objects represent. Only the programmer can implement this logic.

Some object-oriented languages provide a simple "shallow" copy solution for all objects (which would not have been appropriate in the above situation). ObjC provides this for collection objects, but not for generic objects. Instead, you need to implement a strategy by conforming to the `<NSCopying>` protocol.

Just a side bit of history: language support for annotated "properties" is fairly new in ObjC. Before a few years ago, objects knew their ivars, but the runtime had no useful information about what their semantics (such as whether they were copies, strong references, or weak references). This made automatic copies of objects very difficult, even in simple cases. There was an automatic shallow-copy function called `NSCopyObject()`, but it was highly error-prone and [caused much more trouble than it solved](http://robnapier.net/blog/implementing-nscopying-439). Luckily it has finally been deprecated in iOS 6 and OS X 10.8.

Comment: As you said, the "problem" you describe applies to all copies of all objects. So: Why is it possible to solve that problems for objects of other classes but not for managed objects? You do not give a specific reason, why it is possible to solve the "problem" of depth for many, many classes in Cocoa but not for managed objects. The problem of NSCopyObject() was not to decide what to copy, it was not to decide, how to copy but the memory management. This would be no specific problem of managed objects.

Comment: It was not possible to solve the problem for other generic classes. `NSObject` does not conform to `<NSCopying>`, just as `NSManagedObject` does not. There is no special situation here for managed objects. They have exactly the same issues as other objects.

Comment: An implementation in NSObject is not possible, because it can not know what to copy and how to copy. Managed objects are formally well-defined. It is possible to read out the desired information from the model definition, which is available. The situation is not the same. For example a generic copy could copy all attributes, making subclass' code much shorter. (A decision a generic copy for NSObject can not make.)